# Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:3.0.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: opendaylight

Following [this tutorial](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Controller_Core_Functionality_Tutorials:Tutorials:Event_/_Notification_Manager#Subscribing_to_the_Topic), I'm successful to topic creation, got stuck at subscribing to topic.

`mvn install` is failing for `hweventsource` as mentioned below.

And can this feature allow using `odl-hweventsource-uagent` alone when any netconf server (mount point) can generate event notifications?

```
$git clone https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/coretutorials.git

$cd coretutorials

$mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -DskipTests=true


$ mvn clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -DskipTests=true

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/opendaylight/odlparent/odlparent/3.0.2/odlparent-3.0.2.pom

[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.coretutorials:coretutorials-aggregator:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:3.0.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 9, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.coretutorials:coretutorials-aggregator:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/babukt/Downloads/karaf-0.7.2/coretutorials/pom.xml) has 1 error

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.coretutorials:coretutorials-aggregator:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:3.0.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 9, column 11 -> [Help 2]

[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenDaylight artifacts aren’t (yet) available from Maven Central, you need to add our repositories to your Maven configuration. See [the OpenDaylight wiki](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml)  for instructions; the short version is:

```
cp ~/.m2/settings.xml{,.orig}
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml
```

(ignore errors from the `cp` command, it will complain if you don’t already have a Maven settings file).

Regarding your question about `odl-hweventsource-uagent`, I’m not sure what you mean — you should ask that as a separate question and explain what you’re trying to do in more detail.

Comment: This is in the coretutorials project which has not been active/maintained for probably a couple years now.

Comment: @Tom indeed — but is there anything tutorial-like which could be suggested as a replacement?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the hweventsource tutorial (in fact I had never heard of it prior to this post :)) nor do I know who the original authors were.